# “Bazaar” vs. “bazar”

Tags: word-choice, nouns, orthography, vowels, variants

Which of *bazaar* or *bazar* is better to use for the domain name of specialised marketplace?

Both are available according to the dictionaries.

Any advice which of these two is better to use in the URL?

Comment: Which dictionaries? Please link to the definitions if possible.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

(BTW, you really should never just say “the” dictionaries.  State your references.)

You should use *bazaar* with two *a*’s.  Most people would read *bazar* as a spelling mistake.

The OED reports that the bizarre *bazar* spelling was used during the 17<sup>th</sup> through 19<sup>th</sup> centuries, but that early in the 19<sup>th</sup> century (1816) *bazaar* began to be used instead, and the other no longer occurs.

Indeed, *bazaar* is [used about an order of magnitude more frequently](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bazar%2Cbazaar&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=5&share=) than the single-*a* version is.

[image: bazar vs bazaar]

These data support the notion that the old version was phased out early in the 19<sup>th</sup> century.

Comment: Counterpoint: Persian, where the original word bāzār comes from, and essentially every other language other than Dutch, use the two-single-As spelling “bazar”, so IMO using either one in a name could work.

Comment: That said, any idea why there was a switch in the early 19th century? That’s interesting.